# How do you left align a printf on Docker format

Tags: docker, go, go-templates

I am trying to align a set of `docker service ps` calls together using `printf` but it seems to align things on the right when I use `printf`

```
for service in $(command docker service ls --format "{{.Name}}")
do
  command docker service ps \
    --format "table {{ .Name | printf \"%20.20s\" }}\t{{ .Image | printf \"%40.40s\" }}\t{{ .Node | printf \"%20.20s\" }}\t{{.CurrentState}}\t{{.Error}}" \
    $service
done
```

How do I make the `printf` left align?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template's `printf` function uses the [`fmt`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt) package. The `fmt` package documents there's a `-` flag:

> ```
> - pad with spaces on the right rather than the left (left-justify the field)
> ```

So instead of

```
{{ printf "%20.20s" }}
```

Simply use

```
{{ printf "%-20.20s" }}
```

Comment: you can probably remove the last line because if you add remove the initial 20. it will not truncate long values

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano You're right, removed.